# Android Studio: Automatically allow permissions to use camera to take photo and capture video

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera, android-permissions

I created a system that has a camera function. This camera is to take the photo and save it to database. If I want to use the camera function, it will popup a message either to allow the apps to use camera or not. If I press "Allow", I can take the photo from the camera. But when I press "Deny", then if I press back the camera button, the app will stop working.

Thus, I want to make the permission camera is automatically allowed, which means, if the user press camera button, there's no popup message to choose allow or deny. Can any want know how to solve?

Below is my current code for camera

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_update_before);

            EnableRuntimePermission();

            btnCameraBefore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, 7);

                }
            });
        }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 7 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            imgAttachBefore.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            photoBefore();
        }

    }

    public void EnableRuntimePermission(){

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(TaskUpdateBefore.this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA))
        {

            Toast.makeText(TaskUpdateBefore.this,"CAMERA permission allows us to Access CAMERA app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(TaskUpdateBefore.this,new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, RequestPermissionCode);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int RC, String per[], int[] PResult) {

        switch (RC) {

            case RequestPermissionCode:

                if (PResult.length > 0 && PResult[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    Toast.makeText(TaskUpdateBefore.this,"Permission Granted, Now your application can access CAMERA.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(TaskUpdateBefore.this,"Permission Canceled, Now your application cannot access CAMERA.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is not possible to allow permissions automatically.. Especially the ones with `Protection level: dangerous`, these are denied by default. Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: You should never force a permission without a users approval. The solution to your problem should be to redirect back to the screen with your camera button when a user does not accept a permission and show a message explaining that the function wont work without the permission. Then keep asking for the permission on clicks of the camera button.

Comment: @MattJenje how to do that based on my code above? can you edit my code?

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible,it is android security purpose imbedded upon using itshardware services. best way you can do is , prompt the camera permission on startup (you can trigger app that if it doesn't access the permission, you can close the app so that will not work) but if you configure allowing the permission then you should run the application. (by the way,the allowing permission is once, will not popup again)

Answer (score 0):

Typically you will want your user to have access to the rest of your features even when they dont accept all the permissions, and then give them the option to accept the permisison later on.

My suggestion:
Close your camera activity when the permission is not allowed. If you want, you can pass a message through your intent to get displayed on the previous screen. Adding `finishActivity()` should do the trick however without passing through a message.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int RC, String per[], int[] PResult) {

    switch (RC) {

        case RequestPermissionCode:

            if (PResult.length > 0 && PResult[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Toast.makeText(TaskUpdateBefore.this,"Permission Granted, Now your application can access CAMERA.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(TaskUpdateBefore.this,"Permission Canceled, Now your application cannot access CAMERA.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finishActivity();

            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is totally not what I want!

Comment: @RadamelFalcao You don't get it. Asking "How do I bypass Android permissions screen" and asking "How do I create malware that bypasses privacy and security mechanisms on Android" is exactly the same.